# How to fix a socket that works and doesn't work and has a switch in the cord. It is a small one the size of a chandelier bulb.

Tags: light-fixture

25 watt round light bulb in a device that melts wax with fragrance in it goes off after a couple of minutes.  If I mess around with the bulb it will come on and then off again.  This fragrance melter is new and was a gift so want to fix it.  Do you all know how to fix it or buy a new small socket with a switch in the cord?  The socket is only 1 3/8 inch tall and is small like a chandelier bulb socket. Appreciate any help?

Answer (score 1):

The contact in the light socket might be bent too far down.  Unplug the device, remove the lightbulb, gently bend the contact up a little.  The light should work awesomely then.

Comment: Or try a new bulb...

Answer (score 0):

Following Mikes advice is a good way to go to cheaply do it - it can work for you, but it might not work for long either. Some of these components are made very cheaply and so the material is not the highest quality. What can happen is that metal tab gets oxidized over and corrodes - the bulb and the socket can have dissimilar metals. They do sell replacement sockets and sometimes the whole cord/switch and socket at hardware stores such as HD - look in the lighting section near the fans - there is usually an end display with such parts on it.